# Linq statement returning same results for all entries

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to code a linq statement that codes the grade display button so it allows the user to display either all records or only records matching a specific grade. Also it has to calculate a gpa where `a=4`, `b=3`, `c=2`, `d=1`, `f=0`. I have changed the code to implement a where clause but I get 
but i get an error
for the grades saying option strict on disallows implicit conversions from
string to boolean can anyone give me suggestions on this where clause?

```
     Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    dic.Add("A", 4)
    dic.Add("B", 3)
    dic.Add("C", 2)
    dic.Add("D", 1)
    dic.Add("F", 0)



    Dim gpa = Aggregate Grade In CoursesDataSet.tblCourses.AsEnumerable()
       Where Grade.Grade = "A" Or "B" Or "C" Or "D" Or "F"
       Select Grade.Field(Of Integer)("CreditHours") * dic(Grade.Field(Of String)("Grade"))
       Into Sum()




    MessageBox.Show("GPa:" & gpa.ToString(CInt("C2")),
                   "College Courses", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
```

MessageBoxIcon.Information)

```
End Sub
```

End Class

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this exact problem. In fact, we were likely in the same class!
I divided each category of grades into aggregate sums after declaring the letter grades as constants:

```
        Dim ALetterAvg As Double =
        Aggregate ID In CoursesDataSet.tblCourses
        Where ID.Grade.ToUpper = "A"
        Select (ID.CreditHours * gradeAPoints) Into Sum()
```

Aggregated the total number of hours:

```
        Dim totalHours As Double =
        Aggregate hrs In CoursesDataSet.tblCourses
        Select hrs.CreditHours Into Sum()
```

Then divided the grade sums by the total hours:

```
        Dim GPA As Double = (ALetterAvg + BLetterAvg + CLetterAvg + DLetterAvg + FLetterAvg) / totalHours
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable scopes in LINQ queries work the same as anywhere else. So for example if your query is within a loop, your variable Grade has to be in scope for that loop.

It would help in being able to provide a more specific answer if you specify where and how you are currently declaring Grade.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to "translate" `Grade` into corresponding numeric values, i'd suggest to use [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
dic.Add("A", 4)
dic.Add("B", 3)
dic.Add("C", 2)
dic.Add("D", 1)
dic.Add("F", 0)
```

Now, you're able to aggregate data to get sum of Grades.

```
'LinqToDataSet example:
Dim qry = Aggregate r In CoursesDataSet.tblCourses.AsEnumerable()
           Select  r.Field(Of Double)("CreditHours") * dic(r.Field(Of String)("Grade")) 
           Into Sum()
```

For further information, please see: [Linq To DataSet Examples (VB.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399401%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: when i try it this way @Maciej Los I am getting a invalid cast exception error in the select statement

Comment: Change `r.Field(Of Double)("CreditHours")` to proper data type, for example: `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you for your help i changed it to integer but now im getting 68 for all of the grade calculations. I will keep tweeking it

Comment: OK, i'm keeping my fingers crossed for you ;)